# a dynamic list with CI

Tags: php, list, codeigniter

i'm trying to create a multilevel list using codeigniter. the list would look like:

State1

```
city1
city2
```

state2

```
 city3
```

etc.

but when i run the code i get the error

```
            Severity: Notice

            Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$city

           Filename: views/testview.php

         Line Number: 32
```

at line 32 i have:

```
         <?php  foreach($state->city as $city):?>
```

my controller:

```
        //....

   $data['states'] = $this->state_model->get_cities();
   $this->load->view('testview', $data);
```

my model:

```
   function get_cities(){

  $states = $this->db->get('state');

  foreach ($states->result() as $state){
$cities = $this->db->get_where('city', array('state_id'=>$state->id));
$state->cities = $cities->result();
}

 return $states;
```

}

View:

```
   <?php foreach($states as $state):?>
 <h4><?php echo $state->statename;?></h4>
 <?php  foreach($state->city as $city):?>
<?php echo $city->cityname; ?>
 <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 32 to

```
<?php foreach($state->cities as $city): ?>
```

You are looking for the `cities` property. In your model, the city results are assigned to

$state->cities in the $states array.